# libreoffice can not open office files under google drive

Tags: gnome, libreoffice

I just started to use Ubuntu and have a Libre Office problem.

I added my Google account to GNOME accounts.

I can see and reach my files with the Files program. I can open PDF and MP4 files w/o problem.

However Office docs can not be opened by libreoffice; it tries to open but suddenly stops with no error message.

If I copy the doc to local drive, it just works fine.

It looks like a cache problem but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I am using 19.10 version

Comment: After upgrading to 19.10 I started to run into this too. I think you can file this a bug in LibreOffice. I think it is trying create a `.lock` file and fails and because of that thinks the file must be read only.